# How to convert encoded image into .PNG?

Tags: java, javascript, image, base64

How to convert base64-encoded image into .PNG (using Java or JavaScript)?

```
url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABL0lEQVR42q2TLW/DMBCG+1OKworCzMzMAsMCQw0zaGgaahwaXKmsoxuaVD66X3G995Jzk/Rj0rSTXsW+j8cXf+x2/22X7wu1Y0cmVlQEK8IYPsReFiOpjI7CZyFK50gDKx4DtUObQU+LXV9zcifFMHz7o5/ViZBzB0FrsvLoGeDp9HUiNUDgWwq5q98BsUo1+aERLQEK0Zhq1QWIDQNUW4BCNN7Ne7UCuHDT+DHSI3v/eZM4ADidDNjzpOxM1iMAutJ4kzztlwDQDqHM2gIw15jlbmveg1UH2BDbV3xEk5YAjNXvUiWbbbdHiSM5RDsHbQbga6IVwQ8AVkfu3a2U69tP7aEQKqPhYkM2wV9LDDkvbyPoLk3JLV8sCGP4EHtavH1MRbT5MRVz4a+P6S92BSaqyCgd7GKfAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC")
```

Comment: Note that JavaScript should never *need* to convert a base 64 encoded image to anything, it can simply set the data as the `src` of an `image` element and the image should appear in the web page.  Whereas for Java, just convert the string to an input stream and save that stream byte-for-byte to a file.

Answer (score 1):

in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String ecodedData = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABL0lEQVR42q2TLW/DMBCG+1OKworCzMzMAsMCQw0zaGgaahwaXKmsoxuaVD66X3G995Jzk/Rj0rSTXsW+j8cXf+x2/22X7wu1Y0cmVlQEK8IYPsReFiOpjI7CZyFK50gDKx4DtUObQU+LXV9zcifFMHz7o5/ViZBzB0FrsvLoGeDp9HUiNUDgWwq5q98BsUo1+aERLQEK0Zhq1QWIDQNUW4BCNN7Ne7UCuHDT+DHSI3v/eZM4ADidDNjzpOxM1iMAutJ4kzztlwDQDqHM2gIw15jlbmveg1UH2BDbV3xEk5YAjNXvUiWbbbdHiSM5RDsHbQbga6IVwQ8AVkfu3a2U69tP7aEQKqPhYkM2wV9LDDkvbyPoLk3JLV8sCGP4EHtavH1MRbT5MRVz4a+P6S92BSaqyCgd7GKfAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
    Base64 decoder = new Base64();   
    byte[] imgBytes = decoder.decode(ecodedData);  
    FileOutputStream osf;
    osf = new FileOutputStream(new File("yourImage.png"));
    osf.write(imgBytes);  
    osf.flush();        
}
```

This link was used http://www.coderanch.com/t/482256/java/java/Converting-Base-encoded-String-Image, but it has no final working code.

Answer (score 0):

For Java, you can use `DatatypeConverter` to decode that and save whatever it decodes, that should give you a PNG file, if that's what you want.